# Why is my react-scripts build throwing an error with the SourceMapConsumer?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, rubygems, cocoapods, react-scripts

I am building an app in Ionic/react, and up until this point it has functioned normally. I ran into an error with the FFI architecture in Ruby, and ran a brew install ruby, exported the path, and reinstalled cocoapods with brew. Since then, my react-scripts build has failed every time with this error message:

```
You must provide the URL of lib/mappings.wasm by calling SourceMapConsumer.initialize({ 'lib/mappings.wasm': ... }) before using SourceMapConsumer
```

I have done nothing else that would have affected it, and I am struggling finding any relevant information. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated as to how I can resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

It appeared when I used Node 18. Try changing your node instance to 16.

```
nvm use 16
```